# Saved app data in google drive is not showing in backup section

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have implemented data backup using google drive android API in my application. The backup data is being saved to "AppFolder". The data is being saved and retrieved properly. But, the file is not shown when I select "Backups" section in the associated google drive account.

I have set the parameters like below before saving/creating the backup data:

```
String filename = preferences.getString(Constants.USERNAME, Constants.USERNAME_DEF) + "__" + DataHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle(filename)
                                .setMimeType("application/x-sqlite3")
                                .setStarred(true).build();


Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient).createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() { ... });
```

Is there any parameter needed to be added so that the saved data is shown in Backups section in google drive?

Comment: getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient).createFile is this correct?

Comment: Yes. The db file is being uploaded correctly. And, also we can retrieve the file later with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should shed some light in your dilemma:

> What is the App Folder?
>
> **The App Folder is a special folder that is only accessible by your application. Its content is hidden from the user and from other
>   apps.** Despite being hidden from the user, the App Folder is stored
>   on the user's Drive and therefore uses the user's Drive storage quota.
>   The App Folder can be used to store configuration files, temporary
>   files, or any other types of files that belong to the user but should
>   not be tampered with.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the App Folder is actually a secret folder. But, take an example of WhatsApp. When WhatsApp stores it's backup to google drive, the backup file can not be accessed/downloaded by user. But in the google drive "backup" section, the user can see and delete the backup file if he/she wants to.

Comment: how bout create a regular folder and dont place it on appfolder. dont make it complicated for you.

Comment: My main concern was how do I make it appear in the "backups" section in google drive. I hope you understand. thanks.